# How do i automatically scroll a page when it loads in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I  want to automatically scroll to a particular div which is at the bottom of the page my `[data-role="page"]`, but it's not working. The scroll bar still remains at the top  but I want it to scroll down when the page loads. Let me know if you need better explanation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind to the `pageshow` event and then use the `$.mobile.silentScroll()` method to scroll the desired element into view. Here is an example:

```
$(document).delegate('.ui-page', 'pageshow', function () {

    //get the offset of the element
    var offset = $(this).find('[some-element]').offset().top;

    //now scroll to the element
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.mobile.silentScroll(offset);
    }, 0);
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JNSRn/

The `setTimeout` allows the scroll to run after everything else that has been queued to run actually runs.

You can change the `.ui-page` selector to an ID or class to only run this code on a specific page or on a specific set of pages, currently it will run the event handler when any jQuery Mobile pseudo-page is shown.

Docs for `$.mobile.silentScroll()`: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/methods.html (Bottom of page)

Comment: you made my day.May the lord bless you.Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a `anchor` tag and clicking it (you don't even need to attach it to the `DOM`, for example

`var a = $('<a />').attr('href', '#myParticularDiv').click();`